# There is no auto completion when editing in the text input box of debug console,

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, console, completion

When inputting code the text input box of the debug console, There is completions options, but after clicking enter on keyboard, it will not be completed automatically. You need to manually click the completion item with the left mouse button to complete it.So could some optimization be made here. Thank You!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34d9q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDJlQ.png)

Comment: So we can help you out, are you saying that you want the enter key to autocomplete as well as send the command? Have you tried pressing tab to autocomplete before return?

Comment: Let me make that an answer then if that is what you were looking for

Comment: You can now mark the answer as the accepted answer if it was what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tab key to accept what is highlighted in the intellsense drop down in the console.

You can also use the up and down arrow keys to scan through the list.

Hopefully that will keep you from having to switch to mouse. :)